# MSBuild OutDir relative to executed location rather than project location

Tags: msbuild

I'm using MSBuild 15.0 (VS 2017 Enterprise) and trying to get MSBuild's OutDir path to be relative to the current folder.

I have the following folders:

```
C:\MyProject\Tests    (contains the command to build the project)
C:\MyProject\Projects (contains the VS solution/projects)
```

I have the following in `C:\MyProject\Tests\rebuild_all.cmd`:

```
msbuild ..\Projects\MySln.sln /t:Rebuild p:/Configuration=Debug;OutDir=\Debug\
```

This puts a `Debug` folder in each VS project folder rather than in the `\Tests\Debug` folder.

Can I instruct MSBuild to output to a path relative to the current executing environment path, or will it always build relative to the project?

Actually, my final target(s) would be a folder for each project under a relative path of the executing folder:

```
C:\MyProject\Tests\Debug\Project1\(output)
C:\MyProject\Tests\Debug\Project2\(output)
C:\MyProject\Tests\Debug\Project3\(output)
```

Comment: Did you try `msbuild ..\Projects\MySln.sln /t:Rebuild p:/Configuration=Debug;OutDir="%~dp0\Debug\"`?

Comment: @JoséPedro - this got me closer.  I worked it out to `OutDir=%~dp0Debug` which puts everything in the \Tests\Debug folder.  Problem now is that the build for every project is dumped into that folder, rather than one subfolder for each project.  Thanks though, it's closer that what I had

Comment: I would recommend creating a build driver, i.e. a project (like Build.proj), which has the common targets (Build, Rebuild, Clean,...) and project references to all projects you want to build (it works like a solution file), then you can use item metadata and MSBuild properties to achieve what you want. If you're using MSBuild 15.0+, you can also use a Directory.Build.targets file which handles a custom property (like `MyOutDir`), and sets `<OutDir Condition="'$(MyOutDir)' != ''">$(MyOutDir)\$(MSBuildProjectName)</OutDir>`.

Comment: @JoséPedro Interesting... I'll look into that, but on the other hand having the output in my desired structure was more of a nicety rather than requirement, so for that kind of extra work, I might pass on it for the time being.  Thank you!